# Hi, I am a new learner, I could not move ahead problem in location of repository, what should I do with miktex failed to find folder

Tags: pdf

> Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode
> "Tutorial".tex
>
> Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully
> contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
> C:\Users\cit\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
>
> Process exited with error(s)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You really need to provide much more details in order to get an useful answer.

Comment: what does the log file say